# emacs: Which plugin is this?

Tags: emacs, modeline

I have seen many times this 'colourful' plugin but I cannot find which one it is. Any ideas?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is the Nyan Cat, provided by 
[Nyan Mode](https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/NyanMode).

- [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nyan_Cat)
- [Source code](https://github.com/TeMPOraL/nyan-mode/)
- [YouTube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=eWyC6_mzxb4)